# PHP strtotime returning an integer, messing up date calculation

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between two datetime objects, in this case the difference between the current date ($nowDate) and the result I've pulled from a datetime column in MySql ($row['dueDate]' , or $rowDate).  I have set the value in MySql to datetime and I am trying to subtract that time I pull by the current date as represented as a DateTime object.  The problem is that I have tried to convert what I get from MySQL into a DateTime object but

I've tried first using the ::createFromFormat option to try to wrangle the sql output into a usable format, but a php error is thrown claiming the result is a boolean.  When I try using strtotime the error thrown claims it is an integer, and when I try to use the output from the program PHP claims it's a string!

Code below:

```
<?php

            $mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','', 'taskdb'); //open connection

                //retrieve variables

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasklist WHERE completion_flag = FALSE"; //
            $sqldata = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die('error retrieving data');


            //Display results

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><th>Task</th><th>Type</th><th>Due Date</th>";

            $counter = 0;  //may need to make global, not sure


            $results = array();

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                //store each row as variables

                var_dump($row['dueDate']);
                if ($row['externalFlag'] == 1) {
                    $E = 1;
                } else{
                    $E = 0.5;
                }
                //days until completion
                date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
                //$nowDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $nowDate = new DateTime;

                var_dump($nowDate); //tests positive- outputting current time


                $rowDate = strtotime($row['dueDate']); //WHY ISN'T THIS GIVING ME A DATETIME TYPE???



                $D = 1 / (date_diff($nowDate, $rowDate));  //ERROR
                //supposed to put the most recent date first!
```

How do I get the $rowDate variable to be of the dateTime type and not something else?

Answer (score 2):

The [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) needs two [`DateTimeInterface`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) objects as arguments.

```
$nowDate = new DateTime ;
$rowDate = new DateTime("2018-01-05") ;
$diff = date_diff($nowDate, $rowDate) ;
```

Then `$diff` is now a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), not a numeric value. But you can use seconds or microseconds, by example :

```
$seconds = $diff->s ; // integer value
$microseconds = $diff->f ; // float value
```